# Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) OpenLDAP invalid credentials issue

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

This won't be a question, but a solution to an infuriating problem on Ubuntu 10.04. If you tried to deploy an LDAP server using this distro following the tutorials below, you'll be on serious trouble.

The error first appear, on the line: "ldapsearch -xLLL -b cn=config -D cn=admin,cn=config -W olcDatabase=hdb olcAccess"

It simply won't allow admin to access the "cn=config", thus you won't be able to deploy the LDAP server correctly. After almost a week searching for a solution, I've found it!

Quoting the author:

when you get to the setting up ACL part you all of a sudden need to use a cn=admin,cn=config, that doesn't exist

creating a config.ldif with

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: secret

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
```

and adding it with ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f config.ldif

It's unacceptable that a Linux distribution, popular like Ubuntu, have such ridiculous bug. Hope it helps everyone!

Comment: Interesting, but it would be useful to put links to the tutorials you're talking about to get the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a tutorial issue with Ubuntu 10.10. If you refer to

[Ubuntu OpenLDAP Guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html)

and let's say that for now you do everything in order except for setting up replication (the section immediately before that on adding extra schemas is unnecessary at this point also), when you arrive at the section entitled **Setting Up ACL** it doesn't matter what password you try, you'll get `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`...and not because there's a password problem. It's what *gmuller* said.

*gmuller*'s solution above (it's a variant of a solution posted for Karmic Koala) works for me, in exactly the same situation, on Ubuntu 10.10. I had to make the same edits in fact from what is suggested for 9.10 in that second link.

This tutorial defect is not a showstopper for some things. One can **ldapadd** users and groups, and do certain searches.